# How to store number value (or number of the link) with onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, onclick

I have a lot of texts that are displayed using div and anchors.

```
<div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1"><p>blah blah</p></div>
<div class="pageHidden" id="page2"><p>blah blah on a second page</p>/div>
<div class="pageHidden" id="page3"><p>blah blah on a third page</p></div>
```

I use the code below to access to the part of the text, to the pages:

```
 <h2>pages: 
   <a href="#" onclick="showPages('1')">1</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="showPages('3')">3</a>
 </h2>
```

Now I want to make 2 buttons to switch to the next or the previous page, but the problem is that I don't know how to store the value of the current page using this code.

Apparently, `onclick="showPages(id+1)"` only means "go to page 1" in this code. How can I modify that code to be able to tell the browser which "page" I'm viewing, and to increment that value when I click on "next", and reverse when I click on "previous"?

```js
function showPages(id = 1) {
  var totalNumberOfPages = 6;
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfPages; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('page' + i)) {
      document.getElementById('page' + i).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  if (document.getElementById('page' + id)) {
    document.getElementById('page' + id).style.display = 'block';
  }
};
showPages();
```

```html
<div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1">
  <p>blah blah</p>
</div>
<div class="pageHidden" id="page2">
  <p>bloh blouh on a second page</p>
</div>
<div class="pageHidden" id="page3">
  <p>bleuh bleuh on a third page</p>
</div>

<h2>pages :
  <a href="#" onclick="showPages('1')">1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showPages('3')">3</a>
</h2>

<h2>
  <span style="float: left;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(id-1)">Previous</a>
  </span>

  <span style="float: right;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(id+1)">Next</a>
  </span>
</h2><br><br>
```

Comment: Please, can you provide a snippet or a jsFiddle? It would be much easier to understand the current code and see the desired output. To add a snippet, you can [edit] your question and click in the `<>` button

Comment: You need to create a global variable `id` that you fill in with the current page number, then `id+1` and `id-1` will work.

Comment: Sorry. I added a snippet. How can I fill a variable when I click on an anchor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, you need a variable to track the current page.

Based on your code, I've made other modifications as well:

- Use your existing css classes to alter visibility, so it's easier to change other attributes and not necessary any more to initialize them via javascript.
- Check for bounds when clicking Previous / Next.

```js
var current = 1;
var totalPages = document.getElementById("pageContainer").childElementCount;

function showPages(id = 1) {
  if (id < 1 || id > totalPages) 
    return;
  curr_page = document.getElementById("page" + current);
  curr_page.classList.add("pageHidden");
  curr_page.classList.remove("pageDisplayed");

  target_page = document.getElementById("page" + id);
  target_page.classList.add("pageDisplayed");
  target_page.classList.remove("pageHidden");
  current = id;
}
```

```css
.pageHidden {
  display: none;
}

.pageDisplayed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageContainer">
  <div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1">
    <p>blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pageHidden" id="page2">
    <p>blah blah on a second page</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pageHidden" id="page3">
    <p>blah blah on a third page</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>pages :
  <a href="#" onclick="showPages(1)">1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showPages(2)">2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showPages(3)">3</a>
</h2>

<h2>
  <span style="float: left;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(current - 1)">Previous</a>
  </span>

  <span style="float: right;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(current + 1)">Next</a>
  </span>
</h2><br><br>
```

Comment: Correction: It "sort of" works. For some reason, when you click on the third page, then the first page, the "next" function doesn't work anymore. I can't figure out why; it doesn't make any sense to me. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @Braisque yes, it was a type mistake, check updated answer. In essence, by using quotes in `showPages` it was trying to switch to page 11 (string concatenation) instead of 2, so the out of bounds check kicked in.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input field in each page: 
On each click set the pageIdValue and when you click previous or next add / subtract 1 and go to that page as earlier

```html
<input type="hidden" id="pageId" name="pageId" value="pageIdValue">
```